# jquery textbox focus event on infinity loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am using jquery to validate textbox value.

I have 2 textbox, txt1 & txt2. now, i wrote a jquery function.

```
 $("#txt1").blur(function () {

            if ($("#txt1").val() == "") {
                $("#scarriername").show();
                $("#txt1").focus();
            }
            else {
                $("#scarriername").hide();
            }

        });

        $("#txt2").blur(function () {

            if ($("#txt2").val() == "") {
                $("#sscaccode").show();
                $("#txt2").focus();
            }
            else {
                $("#sscaccode").hide();
            }
        });
```

Now, issue is. when i run the project. my position is on txt1 and when u use Tab to go txt2 with null or blank value. Focus event fire for both one & browser become hang due to infinite loop of **FOCUS**.

so, how can i handle it?

Comment: What do you want to achieve ???...

Comment: It's not an infinite loop, everytime the input looses focus, you're telling it to gain focus again if there's no value entered, so what are you expecting ?

Comment: i want....suppose on txt1 i am not entering any value and hit Tab key. i will get errormsg & my focus should be on txt1 box. instead of txt2.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what it's doing ? -> http://jsfiddle.net/NAVss/

Comment: @adeneo: it's work at my side. why it;s not work there. it's not mine issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should insert a `setTimeout` in order to set the focus after the `blur` event.

Second, you should insert a semaphore in order to avoid a loop (see code and comments):

```
var status = "valid"; // semaphore

$("#txt1").blur(function (e) {

    // if we are in programmatically focus, ignore this handler
    if(status == "invalid") 
        return ;

     if ($("#txt1").val() == "") {
         $("#scarriername").show();

         // set semaphore
         status = "invalid";

         // use setTimeout in order to set focus in the right moment
         setTimeout(function() {$("#txt1").focus(); status = "valid"},0);
     }
     else {
         $("#scarriername").hide();
     }

 });

// same as txt1
$("#txt2").blur(function () {
    if(status == "invalid") 
        return ;
    if ($("#txt2").val() == "") {
        $("#sscaccode").show();
        setTimeout(function() {$("#txt2").focus(); status = "valid"},0);

    }
    else {
        $("#sscaccode").hide();
    }
});
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/SszUf/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" />
<input type="text" id="txt2" />

$("#txt2").focus(function () {
 if ($("#txt1").val() == "") {
        $("#scarriername").show();
        $("#txt1").focus();
    } 
    //alert(1);    
});
```

hope this help you

Comment: No. It will lead to infinite loop if he add the same condition for txt1 focus also

Comment: i have more thn 20 textbox...so, it;s not possible to set this condition for every one.possibility user can jump txt1 to txt5 via mouse...at that time it will be not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#txt1").blur(function () {

            if ($("#txt1").val() == "") {
                $("#scarriername").show();
                if ($("input:focus").length == 0)
                $("#txt1").focus();
            }
            else {
                $("#scarriername").hide();
            }

        });
```

Just add a line can solve this problem

**By the way, the `#scarriername` should not be something like popup window, which will trigger other blur events**

You can test the file below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="txt1"><input id="txt2"><input id="txt3"><input id="txt4">
<hr>
<h1 id="h1"></h1>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("input").blur(function () {
 if ($(this).val() == "") {
        document.getElementById("h1").innerHTML += "123";
        $(this).focus();
    }     
});});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: did u test this thing at your side? i dont think so, it should work and also i tested it....no HOPE... :(

Comment: Come on, I edit my answer, and upload my code, just test it now! I tested for 4 textbox

Answer (score 0):

Apparently when you hit the tab button you trigger blur event for both text boxes. With your code when txt1 gets blurred and has no content you get the focus on txt1, but when you do that you also trigger the blur event for txt2 and since it does not have any text in it you get the focus back to txt2. This keeps on going and going, focusing on txt1 and then txt2 and then txt1 and then txt2... You could put a simple if check on the second blur event handler to see if txt1 is still empty, and if so keep the focus on txt1 not allowing the client to pass to txt2:

```
 $("#txt1").blur(function () {

            if ($("#txt1").val() == "") {
                $("#scarriername").show();
                $("#txt1").focus();
            }
            else {
                $("#scarriername").hide();
            }

        });

        $("#txt2").blur(function () {

            if ($("#txt2").val() == "" && $("#txt1").val() != "") {
                $("#sscaccode").show();
                $("#txt2").focus();
            }
            else {
                $("#sscaccode").hide();
            }
        });
```

Comment: i have more thn 20 textbox...so, it;s not possible to set this condition for every one.possibility user can jump txt1 to txt5 via mouse...at that time it will be not work.

Comment: Then may be you should do the checking when user tries to submit the form. Check all of them at once.

Answer (score 0):

This is also one of the approach to solve your problem on pressing tab key.

```
$("#txt1").bind('keydown',function(e)
{
    if(e.keyCode == 9)
    {
        if ($("#txt1").val() == "") {
            $("#scarriername").show();
            return false;                
        }
        else {
            $("#scarriername").hide();
        }
    }
});
$("#txt2").bind('keydown',function(e)
{
    if(e.keyCode == 9)
    {
        if ($("#txt2").val() == "") {
            $("#sscaccode").show();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $("#sscaccode").hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: return false prevents the tab navigation. so the cursor will be remain in the current input box and not focus to the next one